# How can I remove a swf file that's embedded in html using timer

Tags: javascript, html, flash, embed, swfobject

I having trouble to remove my short animation on my webpage. I have this embed code on my webpage, but I dont know how to remove or close this swf file. Here my code for embedding my swf file

```
    <div style="position:absolute; margin-left:250px; z-index:1;">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="800" height="500" title="pattern">
  <param name="movie" value="../gift/pattern/10/pink rose.swf">
  <param name="quality" value="high">
  <param name="wmode" value="direct">
  <param name="menu" value="false" />
  <embed src="../gift/pattern/10/pink rose.swf" width="800" height="500" loop="false" menu="false" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" ></embed>
</object>
</div>
```

I want to remove the animation after animation is done with countdown timer on javascript method , so that's will be automaticly remove after play. Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this through javascript

```
function Delete() {
  var element = document.getElementById("element-id");
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
setTimeout(Delete, 1000);
```

Comment: modern browsers have a `.remove()` method on nodes, use that and the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill) for modern code